# sEden framework for omnet issues using namespace sql fails

Tags: mysql, omnet++

I'm trying to implement SDN project in ***omnet***. I installed `inet`, `sdncontroller`, `omnet` on **windows 10**, but have some issues:

"Using namespace sql" fails see image

[image: sqlApi.cc and xmlApi.cc not included in project]

Question is that How should I integrate sql database with omnet?

Comment: Could you provide [mcve]?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.